# Set Responsive Width For Linkedin Company Profile plugin

Tags: javascript, css, responsive-design, linkedin-api

I want to use LinkedIn Company Profile plugin in my responsive website. I have added the `data-width="300"` for desktop view, now I want to set some different width value for tablet and mobile devices.

Can anyone help me on how can I set different values in `data-width` for different views.

Comment: Please add some codes, for better helps ;).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of what you can do :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>test</title>
        <style>
            @media screen and (max-width:760px) {
                #linkedinXsSmall {display: block;}
                #linkedinSmall {display: none;} 
                #linkedinMedium {display: none;} 
                #linkedinDesktop {display: none;}  
            }

            @media screen and (min-width:761px) and (max-width:960px) {
                #linkedinXsSmall {display: none;}
                #linkedinSmall {display: block;} 
                #linkedinMedium {display: none;} 
                #linkedinDesktop {display: none;} 
            }

            @media screen and (min-width:961px) and (max-width:1280px) {
                #linkedinXsSmall {display: none;} 
                #linkedinSmall {display: none;} 
                #linkedinMedium {display: block;} 
                #linkedinDesktop {display: none;} 
            }
            /* apply to all larger devices */
            @media screen and (min-width:1281px) {
                #linkedinXsSmall {display: none;} 
                #linkedinSmall {display: none;} 
                #linkedinMedium {display: none;} 
                #linkedinDesktop {display: block;} 
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="http://platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <div id="linkedinXsSmall">
            <script type="IN/CompanyProfile" data-id="1337" data-format="inline" data-width="200px"></script>
        </div>

        <div id="linkedinSmall">
            <script type="IN/CompanyProfile" data-id="1337" data-format="inline" data-width="400px"></script>
        </div>

        <div id="linkedinMedium">
            <script type="IN/CompanyProfile" data-id="1337" data-format="inline" data-width="600px"></script>
        </div>

        <div id="linkedinDesktop">
            <script type="IN/CompanyProfile" data-id="1337" data-format="inline" data-width="1000px"></script>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Also don't forget to use:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

in your page so that the content is scaled appropriately on devices with high pitch.

I've choosen this solution because it's quick to set up and easy to understand. To my mind it should be also possible to do it with a javascript that would initialize data-with but it is a bit more tricky.

Comment: Hi,Thank you so much for the prompt reply, but I cannot use the above css as Linkedin Company Profile plugin comes with only 2 JavaScript sources and we need to pass the width values in JavaScript source with data-width. Please see:- [<script type="IN/MemberProfile" data-id="http://www.linkedin.com/in/xxx" data-format="inline" data-width="400"></script>]

Comment: I've updated my answer now that I know what you want exactly. Feel free to mark it as a the good answer if it is what you want. Next time provide more details immediately so that the answers will be more accurate.